# How can I process every file in my S3 bucket with bash?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bunch of large files (100MB - 1GB) in a Bucket. I would like to "map" all those files using a bash script. I am unable to download all files at once because my computer does not have enough storage.

Does anyone have an idea how I can do this? Anything smarter than the following solution?

```
for file in $(aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev) ; do 
    aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/$file $file;
    ./script;
    aws s3 cp $file s3://my-bucket/$file;
    rm $file;
done
```

**Explanation:**

`$(aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev)` gets the name of the files in the bucket over which we are iterating

`aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/$file $file` downloads a single file

`./script` runs my custom script

`aws s3 cp $file s3://my-bucket/$file` overwrites the old file with the new one

Comment: It seems odd to `rm $file` prior to copying it back to s3.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Obviously a stupid mistake

Comment: You should double-quote all instances of `$file` and remove all superfluous semi-colons.

Comment: My question regards more the nature of my approach. Is there anything smarter than "download each file from S3, process locally, upload again?"

Comment: Answer to your question: no, because S3 is simply storage, not compute. However, I'd recommend running your scripts on an EC2 instance, because (1) it probably has higher bandwidth than your PC, and (2) you're charged for data transfer to the Internet (and it can be significant), but not to an EC2 instance running in the same region (unless there's a NAT in the way).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting approach to reverse and reverse again - I would never have thought of that, but now one day might.

Taking the context as bash as per the title.  Depending on what your script does, you could use other services like Glue for a "smarter"/faster but more complex solution.

I suppose you don't have any "folders" (prefixes) in your bucket.  A more configurable and probably more reliable way to get the list to process could be to use the `s3api`, e.g.:

```
objects=$(aws s3api list-objects \
            --bucket my-bucket   \
            --output json        \
            --query "Contents[].Key")
for file in $(echo $objects | jq -r '.[]'); do
    aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/$file $file;
    ./script;
    aws s3 cp $file s3://my-bucket/$file;
    rm $file;
done
```

This assumes you'd have `jq` installed.

The above doesn't need handling of "folders".  You can also do some nicer things like choose a "subfolder" to process, e.g.:

```
            --prefix path/to/process/   \
```

or filter on a file extension, e.g.:

```
            --query "Contents[?contains(Key, '.mp4')].Key")
```

Might be nice to use prefixes to be able to handle restarts of the script or list limits being hit (e.g. default `--page-size` of 1000 for `aws s3 ls`).